Phone Auth verification SMS contains ***.firebaseapp.com as the APP_NAME
I have a flutter application which is now ready for prod release. As one of the remaining tests before the release, I have to test phone authentication with real sms. The authentication with fake phone numbers works fine.
My issue is that in the sms the app name has a weird suffix .firebaseapp.com.
I have read at many places that I should activate Google as provider to edit the public facing name, what I did. But the prefix still remain in the sms.
I have also read somewhere that the public facing name only works for email authentication.
I just want to have clarity (if possible) to avoid spending hours trying to fix something that is not fixable.

I Just found out the answer. For those who have the same issue.
Here from the firebase documentation on enabling app verification:

When SafetyNet or Play Integrity is used for App verification, the %APP_NAME% field in the SMS template is populated with the app name determined from Google Play Store. In the scenarios where reCAPTCHA is triggered, %APP_NAME% is populated as PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com.

This is what I was looking for.
